# Timing Diagram - HyperBus - HyperFlash - HyperRAM - RWDS - CLK - DQ

Tags: timing, time, timing-analysis, ddr, sdr

I'm trying to design an interface between an application processor and a HyperFlash memory from Cypress. Therefore, I'm trying to understand the timing diagram for RWDS and DQs relative to the CLK line. Here is the timing diagram representing the valid and invalid areas of the given signals:

(Clock frequency is set to **166 MHz** and the operating voltage is equal to **1.8V**)

[image: Timing Parameters]

This is how the clock signal looks like:

[image: Clock Parameters]

I am trying to recreate the timing diagram using a third-party application, to design the interface to guarantee the minimum setup and hold timings etc. Here is how it looks like: (Measurement level is VccQ/2)

[image: Possible cases]

I have created 2 scenarios, based on the datasheet values and both seems to be incorrect.

The first is where the RWDS valid region (t_CKDS) tracks the CLK transition on both edges. That's how I understood at first, according to the datasheet. However, in this scenario, the valid area of the RWDS signal is nonexistent. Minimum time to the RWDS valid is specified as 1 ns, the maximum is 5.5 ns, relative to the CLK. Well, the positive and negative clock width is equal to 3 ns typical (let's ignore any jitter etc.). So, until the next transition of the CLK, there isn't enough time for the RWDS to be valid. Same is applied to the DQx lines in this example.

In the second scenario (since the first one failed), I drew the t_CKDS only on the rising/falling edge of the CLK/CLK# signal. That gives the RWDS a valid area of 1.5 ns. However, it should be minimum 2.46 ns, according to the xSPI specification as far as I am concerned. Also, this gives the DQx signal a valid area of 600 ps maximum. On the datasheet the data valid has a minimum value of 1.7 ns (t_DV).

It seems like to match the datasheet timing (read operation, t_CKDS, t_CKD, t_CKDI, t_DV, t_DSS, t_DSH) values, the clock frequency must be around ~65 MHz maximum. However, the values are listed for 133 MHz operation.

Plus, the CK transition to DQ/RWDS valid time delays appear to be fixed over the whole frequency of operation range. Could it be really fixed or is it more of a print mistake in the datasheet?

Obviously, I am missing something here. I'll be glad if anyone experienced can be of any help and point that out. How to interpret this timing diagram with the given values? What is the reason for the timing mismatches here? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: The datasheet specs are what the manufacturer guarantees. For things like setup and hold times, they are not related to the clock speed as they are determined by physical delays in the chip. These delays vary with vcc, temperature and the chip itself. Similarly with clock to output delays. Regardless of the clock speed, the output is guaranteed stable  the specified time after the clock edge.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree with your comment. The part I don't understand in this example is that the manufacturer guarantees the data valid time (t_DV) to be at least 1.7 ns for 166 MHz operation. But at 166 MHz CLK frequency, with given delays (t_CKDS, t_CKD, t_CKDI), it seems like the RWDS and DQs signals have no valid area. In order to satisfy the datasheet timings above, it seems like the CLK frequency can be ~65 MHz maximum. Above frequencies with given guaranteed delay timings shorten the data valid region for RWDS and DQs. Not sure how to do a worst-case analysis in this case.

Comment: What i think it is telling us is that rwds and dq can be skewed 1...5.5ns from the rising edge of the clock. So you clock dq in on rwds, not clock. The data transfer can lag by up to nearly one clock period.

Comment: I suspected the same thing. I find it odd though since it doesn't give any information on the RWDS valid time (max). I'll try to derive it from the DQ and also the xSPI specification combined. Thanks again.